# Using Case On Query

Tags: sql

I want to get value from table chat using case, like this :

```
SELECT user_one, user_two
FROM chatting, users
WHERE
CASE 
WHEN user_one = 36 
THEN user_two = 55
WHEN user_two = 55 
THEN user_one = 36 
END
```

but i get this error after "THEN user_two = 55"
The error is "Incorrect syntax near '='."

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to make a logical expression the predicate of a `CASE` expression.  That is, what follows `THEN` and `ELSE` has to be literal values.  But, we can rewrite your logic as:

```
SELECT
    user_one,
    user_two
FROM chatting c
INNER JOIN users u
    -- ON <some condition>
WHERE
    (user_one = 36 AND user_two = 55) OR (user_one = 55 AND user_two = 36);
```

Depending on your version of SQL, we might be able to write the `WHERE` clause using tuples, as:

```
WHERE
    (user_one, user_two) IN ((36, 55), (55, 36));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need just

```
   where (user_one =36 and user_two = 55)
```